# Searching element in jsonb_array_elements(2D array)

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with 2 column R(id int,dat jsonb). The b column jsonb consist of a 2D array [][]. For example :

```
id| dat
1 | {"name":"a","numbers":[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[1,3]]}
2 | {"age":5,"numbers":[[1,1]]}
3 | {"numbers":[[5,6],[6,7]]}
```

I'm trying to find all the ids that contain a specific number in one of those sub arrays. I used 2 solutions and I want to understand why the first one isn't working :

1)

```
select * from R 
where exists (
    select from jsonb_array_elements(R.dat->'numbers')->>0 first,jsonb_array_elements(range.data->'numbers')->>1 second where first::decimal= 1 and second::decimal= 1
);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "->>"
LINE 3: ...t from jsonb_array_elements(R.dat->'numbers')->>0 first,j...
```

2. 

```
SELECT *
FROM  R 
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM jsonb_array_elements(R.dat-> 'numbers') subarray
   WHERE (subarray->>0)::decimal = 1 and (subarray->>1)::decimal = 1
   );
```

In addition, I saw that gin index doesn't handle this operator so basically does any index will help here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query raises an error because you can use only [table experssions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html) (not value expressions) in the `FROM` clause.

You can make the second query a bit simpler:

```
select *
from  r
where exists (
    select from jsonb_array_elements(dat->'numbers') subarray
    where subarray = '[1,1]'
    );
```

or using the function in a lateral join:

```
select r.*
from r
cross join jsonb_array_elements(dat->'numbers')
where value = '[1,1]';
```

There is no index that could support these queries because of the use of `jsonb_array_elements()`.

You may be tempted to use the containment operator `@>` in the way like this:

```
select *
from r
where dat->'numbers' @> '[[1,1]]'::jsonb

 id |                            dat                             
----+------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"name": "a", "numbers": [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 3]]}
  2 | {"age": 5, "numbers": [[1, 1]]}
(2 rows)
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, it does not work as you could expect. The use of the operator on arrays is a bit tricky, as it works in the way: `array1 @> array2` is true if for each element `j` of `array2`, there is an `i` in `array1` such that `i @> j`. Hence, per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-CONTAINMENT)

> the order of array elements is not significant when doing a containment match, and duplicate array elements are effectively considered only once.